# Modifying index of a MongoDB collection in Spring Boot migration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, indexing, migration, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.4 and MongoDB. I have an entity 'MyClass' that had an index on a field. I want to modify that index and add unique constraint on that index.

Previously:

```
@Document(collection = "myclass")
public class MyClass {
  ...
  @Indexed
  private String id;
  ..
}
```

New:

```
@Document(collection = "myclass")
public class MyClass {
  ...
  @Indexed(unique = true)
  private String id;
  ..
}
```

The application fails to start when I add the unique constraint because it complains about an index already defined with different configuration. Since I have to drop the index first and create a new index that adjusts to the new unique constraint, I wanted to perform some automated migration to adjust the indexes.

I tried running migration using Mongock, but the application fails before running the migration as the entity classes is being evaluated before the migration kicks in.

I want to be able to perform the migration before the application starts so that the class state reflects the change in the index. I want to automate using migration script and avoid running commands on the database, and need it after deploying it to the server. There are multiple profiles, and the respective mongoDB database are picked up for that profile from application.yml file. Onviously it would nice to write to the MongoChangeSets to reflect that the migration has been done so it doesn't run twice.

Any pointers on tools or how to achieve it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Documentation suggests that you can't modify any index options other than TTL expiry: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/manage-indexes/#modify-an-index

Comment: As I stated in the initial description, I want to drop the index and add a unique index through migration and have the classes reflect that.